# When designing UDP packet structure, should all byte lengths come first?

Tags: networking, architecture, network-programming, udp, packet

This may raise some opinionated answers, but are there any reasons to design your UDP packet structure like this...

1) `DATA1_LENGTH | DATA2_LENGTH | ... | DATA1 | DATA2 | ...`

instead of a more **serial-like** fashion like so?

2) `DATA1_LENGTH | DATA1 | DATA2_LENGTH | DATA2 | ..._LENGTH | ...`

With the 1st method, it feels like there's more data preparation involved to calculate each piece of data's byte lengths in advance.

The 2nd method can pretty much just advance a `byte length` index / offset to write consecutive pieces of data one after the other, regardless of it's type or relevance to the previous chunk of data.

Are there any reasons to pack the byte lengths in a header first before the actual data?

Comment: There is no technical reason to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't **really** matter all that much, but if it were up to me, I'd prefer the second method as it seems a bit easier to build and parse. There's less state involved and the chunks are independent of each other.